# Should I use int32 or int64 for the primary keys in my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

When creating a new database in SQL Server, should I use primary keys as int32 or int64?

Is the int32 faster?

I think the reason that I would not want to go with int32 is that: wouldn't the upper limit on the int32 datatype limit the total transactions on a particular table to 2,147,483,647? I have no intention of storing that much data in there, but what if I constantly needed to create new records and then delete others that were stale? many transactions later, wouldn't I run out of keys? Is there some method that takes care of this already? Or should I just use the long data type.

Comment: I don't think there is a performance impact if you have a int64 (BigInt) column as a primary key instead of int32 (Int).

Comment: You get 4 billion rows. Just (re)start the identity seed at negative 2 billion.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli: **OF COURSE** there is a performance impact! Quick a massive one, even, if that column is the primary key (and thus by default the clustering key) of your SQL Server table. The **clustering key** is included into each and every nonclustered index on that same table - and thus, it's stored quite a few times - and having 8 bytes vs. 4 bytes can make **quite a difference** when you're dealing with hundreds of millions of rows....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the clarification. I myself use BigInt as primary key in few tables. I may have to re-structure them. However what would be the response time impact as it is asked in the question?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli: if you have a really large number of rows (millions and more), and potentially a lot of nonclustered indices on a table - then yes, it would definitely be a good idea to see if you can move to an `int` instead of `bigint`

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli: the impact on response time is this: if your data needs more space (on disk), it is spread out over more 8k pages in SQL Server, so in order for a given query to be satisfied, SQL Server must load more pages --> has a direct impact on I/O from your disk subssystem.

Comment: There are exceptions to this rule, if you do a huge number of inserts and deletes, then while you may not have 2.1 Billion rows, you may have done 2.1 Billion inserts. Again better design practices should be considered in this case.

Comment: All of the answers so far discuss the limits on record count.  However, I have an application that typically has only hundreds of records per table but for which processing time in the app itself is crucial.  As as result, I have used bigint so that my application does not have to convert from 32 bit to 64 bit for all its calculations.  IOW, all of my app variables are 64 bit numbers.  How does that play into the answers?

Also, some of my queries have LOTS of joins.  Does that affect whether I should use 32- or 64- identity fields?

Answer (score 38):

With a type `INT` (int32), starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT` (int64), you get roughly **9 quintillion** (9 with 18 zeros - 9'223'000 billions) - enough for you??

Just a few quick calculations:

- If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you **insert a row every second**, you need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....
- If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you **insert one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 9.22 quintillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: This should be 9 quintillion, 223 quadrillion...  9 with 18 zeros following:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807

Comment: Though, if you're logging user actions and 10k of them happen every second (else, why to use MSSQL?), that means that 2billion limit will be enough for just a couple of days! And with 1k of events every second INT (int32) will not be enough even for a month.

Comment: I can't help but comment on how beautiful is this answer!!